# EntityTypeConfiguration in Entity Framework 6 RC1

Tags: entity-framework

Is there any reason to specify all the columns in each table like this

```
this.HasKey(t => t.EmployeeID);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.LastName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(20);
```

And if is it, why?

Comment: if you don't use Entity Configuration it uses default configuration for your Tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking if there's another way to specify `not null` and `nvarchar(n)`, you can also use attributes from the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace.

```cs
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```